# Durandal 2.0 Modal dialog

Tags: plugins, knockout.js, dialog, durandal

I am trying to make durandal custom modal dialog work. I am stuck with many issues.

1) I could not get the dialog show up with simple html with a button on it, as view.

My Custom dialog:

```
define(['knockout', 'durandal/app', 'viewmodels/shell'], function (ko, app, shell) 
{

    var vm =
     {

         buttonCancel: buttonCancel,

         canActivate: function () {
             return true;
         },

         activate: function () {
         },

         attached: function () {

         },

         canDeactivate: function () {
             return true;
         }, 
     };

    function buttonCancel() {
        dialog.close(vm, 1);
    }

    return vm; 
});
```

Custom View:

```
<div>
   Hello There!
     <input type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-bind="click:   buttonCancel">Close</input><br/>
<input type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-bind="click: buttonCancel">Close</input><br />
<input type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-bind="click: buttonCancel">Close</input><br />
</div>
```

From the parent view model, I am calling the above custom dialog as follows:

app.showDialog(testmodal, {title: 'hello'});
//testmodal is require('viewmodels/testmodal');

when the above fn is being called, it looks like something is popping up, as i can see the top logo of my current view disappers, but the custom modal does not really showup.

i could not find any good example on how a normal durandal viewmodel with durandel events implemented can be used as custom modal dialog.

Note: I have another viewmodel which I can invoke with same above code, but when I try to click a button on the modal which is binded to a function that closes the dialog (from within in the dialog) throws the error as follows:

'activator.js:141 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined'.

Can anyone help me provide a fiddle on how a typical viewmodel with durandel events and observables, can be invoked as modal dialogue and closed with a button click on the dialog? I am really excited to get this implemented and I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Appreciate your help.